# What if I run the collate_fn outside the DataLoader?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader, data-preprocessing

The traditional way of applying some arbitrary collate_fn `foo()` in [torch](https://pytorch.org/) code is

```py
dataloader = torch.data.DataLoader(
  dataset,
  batch_size=64, # just for example
  collate_fn=foo,
  **other_kwargs
)

for batch in dataloader:
    # incoming batch is already collated
    do_stuff(batch)
```

But what if (for whatever reason), I wanted to do it like this:

```py
dataloader = torch.data.DataLoader(
  dataset,
  batch_size=64, # just for example
  **other_kwargs
)

for batch in dataloader:
    # incoming batch is not yet collated
    # this let's me do additional pre-collation stuff like
    # batch = do_stuff_precollate(batch) 
    collated_batch = foo(batch)  # finally we collate, outside of the dataloader
    do_stuff(collated_batch)
```

Is there any reason why the latter is a big nono? Or why the former is particularly advantageous? I found a [blogpost that even suggests that for HF tokenisation, the latter is faster](https://sachinruk.github.io/blog/pytorch/huggingface/2021/11/17/collate-fn-vs-normal.html)